# What are the requirements on the initialization and animation functions used by matplotlib's FuncAnimation?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

What are the requirements on the initialization (`init_func`) and animation (`func`) arguments to [matplotlib's `FuncAnimation`](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation)?

In [all](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/) [the](http://sam-dolan.staff.shef.ac.uk/mas212/lectures/l5.pdf) [examples](http://blog.e-svet.si/2013/09/drawing-chart-dynamically-with-python-and-matplotlib/) I can find, both functions seem to always rely on using (1) global matplotlib instances that are, (2) associated with the figure being drawn, which are (3) changed exclusively through instance methods, and (4) returned by each function. For example:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))   # (1)(2)
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)              # (1)(2)

# for init_func argument
def init():
    global line                            # (1)
    line.set_data([], [])                  # (3)
    return line,                           # (4)

# for func argument
def animate(i):
    global line                            # (1)
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x, y)                    # (3)
    return line,                           # (4)
```

Are all of these elements required for animation to work, or can I write any code that changes elements of the figure (`fig`) in the two functions?

If these elements are required, how would I, for example, write an animation function to change (add, remove, reposition and resize) several annotations and lines, such as

```
 ax.annotate("Some text 1", (x1, y1), ... )
 ax.annotate("Some text 1", (x1, y1), ... )
 ...
 ax.annotate("Some text N", (xN, yN), ... )
 ...
 ax.plot(... )
 ax.plot(... )
```

Comment: I was similarly wondering about modifying an element using this technique. If you figure it out,  please post an answer!